# Trying to flatten array in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I'm new to numpy and trying to flatten a 1000,1000 array created from a pandas dataframe. the code i've used is:

```
    lidor_array=lidor_df.values
    print(lidor_array.shape)
    lidor_array.flatten()
    print(lidor_array.shape)
```

the shapes are output as (1000,1000) for both the pre and post flattened array. what am i missing?

many thanks for your help

Comment: "`what am i missing?`" - Not assigning back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flatten` is not performed in-place. It returns a copy:

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.flatten.html

You could either do:

```
lidor_array.flatten().shape
```

or

```
lidor_array_flat = arr.flatten()
print lidor_array_flat.shape
```